# spring async method call with JPA transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am implementing a backend service with Spring Boot. This service receives a REST request and executes some database operations and finally updates the status of the record.

After that, I would like to start a new async process and execute another data manipulation on the same record this way:

```
@Service
public class ClassA {

    @Autowired
    private ClassB classB;

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething(Long id) {
        // executing the business logic
        if (isOk()) {
            repo.updateStatus(id, Status.VERIFIED)
        }

        // I need to commit this DB transaction and return.
        // But after this transaction is committed, I need
        // to start an async process that must work on the
        // same record that was updated before.
        classB.complete(id);
    }
}
```

And this is my async method:

```
@Service
public class ClassB {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repo;

    @Async
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void complete(Long id) {
        Optional<MyEntity> myEntity = repo.findById(id);
        if (myEntity.isPresent() && myEntity.get().getStatus == Status.VERIFIED) {
            // execute 'business logic B' 
        }
    }
}
```

The `classA.doSomething()` is called multiply times with the same `id` but `business logic B` must be executed only when the record status in the DB is `VERIFIED`.

The above solution works fine.

But my concern is the following: My test database is small and the `classA.doSomething()` method always finishes and closes its transaction BEFORE the `classB.complete()` starts to check the status of the same record in the DB. I see in the log that the SQLs are executed in the proper order:

```
* UPDATE STATUS FROM TABLE ... WHERE ID = 1 // doSomething()
* COMMIT
* SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1          // complete()
```

But is that 100% guaranteed that the 1st, `classA.doSomething()` method will always finish and commit the transaction before the 2nd `classB.complete()` async call check the status of the same record?

If the async method `classB.complete()` will be executed before `classA.doSomething()` finishes and execute its DB commit then I will break the business logic and the `business logic B` will be skipped (the new DB transaction will not see the updated status yet) and that will cause a big issue. Maybe this can happen if the database is huge and the commit takes longer than it takes in my small test DB.

Maybe I can operate with the DB transaction isolation levels described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html) but changing this can cause another issue in another part of the app.

What is the best way to implement this logic properly which guarantees the proper execution order with the async method?

Comment: Maybe you can use flush to ensure that VERIFIED is persisted DB before complete method. Also why do you need async method without task executor? I guess it takes time to complete method to execute but you need a scheduler approach if you need time to execute. Single thread can handle multiple verified object.

Comment: NOT GUARANTEED! The transaction of `doSomething` will end (the soonest, i.e. if not called in the context of a transaction started by a previous method) at its closing `}`. `ClassB` has the opportunity to run to completion. I would place the 1st part of `doSomething` in a separate `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction method (you may need to place it in a different class, depending on how you configured transaction interceptors). Then, `doSomething` calls the 1st part method, which finishes in a new transaction, then `ClassB` can continue asynchronously.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos could you please post your suggestion as a solution? It works and I would like to accept it as a solution. Thx.

Comment: There is one small issue with the solution above. If the inner transaction committed but the outer fails, i need to execute a "compensation" on a microservice way and revert the status manually. After all, i think that the best and robust way to make the classB.complete async is to add a JMS queue between the two methods. Spting does not offer any nice solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT GUARANTEED that "*the 1st, `classA.doSomething()` method will always finish and commit the transaction before the 2nd `classB.complete()` async call check the status of the same record*".

Transactions are implemented as some kind of interceptors appropriate for the framework (this is true for CDI too). The method marked `@Transactional` is intercepted by the framework, so the transaction will not end before the closing `}` of the method. As a matter of fact, if the transaction was started by another method higher in the stack, it will end even later.

So, `ClassB` has plenty of time to run and see inconsistent state.

I would place the 1st part of `doSomething` in a separate REQUIRES_NEW transaction method (you may need to place it in a different class, depending on how you configured transaction interceptors; if you are using AOP, Spring may be able to intercept calls to methods of the same object, otherwise it relies on the injected proxy object to do the interception and calling a method through `this` will not activate the interceptor; again this is true for other frameworks as well, like CDI and EJB). The method `doSomething` calls the 1st part method, which finishes in a new transaction, then `ClassB` can continue asynchronously.

Now, in that case (as correctly pointed out in the comment), there is a chance that the 1st transaction succeeds and the 2nd fails. If this is the case, you will have to put logic in the system about how to compensate for this inconsistent state. Frameworks cannot deal with it because there is not one recipe, it is a per case "treatment". Some thoughts, in case they help: make sure that the state of the system after the 1st transaction clearly says that the second transaction should complete "shortly after". E.g. keep a "1st tx committed at" field; a scheduled task can check this timestamp and take action if it is too far in the past. JMS gives you all this - you get retries and a dead letter queue for the failed cases.